# codeigniter controller input default value as 1

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to insert datebase in codeigniter with default value = 1 for every row input

here's my controller

```
$data['status']          = $this->input->post(1);
```

your help would be very much appreciated

Comment: add some more content please

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = array(
   'title' => $title ,
   'name' => $name,
   'id2'  => 1 # default value
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

or

In database set `column to NOTNULL` and set ***`default value to 1`***

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this in your model

```
if ($this->input->post('status')!='') {
    $data['status'] = $this->input->post('status');
} else {
    $data['status'] = 1;
}
```